# Serving nodejs static files in the same domain as my PHP

Tags: php, node.js, nginx, static-files

I have website which running on PHP, but also I have NodeJS app which is running on the same domain.
NodeJs address is `/nodejs`, all other requests are under PHP.

- PHP project located in folder `/home/php-project`
- PHP static files folder `/home/php-project/public`
- NodeJS is located in - `/home/nodejs-project`.
- NodeJS static files folder `/home/nodejs-project/public`

Is it possible to serve different static folders?

Here is my NodeJs code

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Currently all static files coming from php static folder and I can't get access to nodejs static files.

Here is the nginx config

```
server {
    listen         80;
    server_name    www.example.com example.com;
    return         301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

   #### Comodo SSL
    ssl_certificate path/to;
    ssl_certificate_key path/to;

    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name   www.example.com;

    #### Comodo SSL
    ssl_certificate path/to;
    ssl_certificate_key path/to;

    root /home/php-project/public;
    index index.php;


    location / {
        autoindex off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /node-js {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5555;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_buffering off;
        root /home/node-js;   
    }


} #### End server setup
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
location / {
  root /home/php-project/public;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string @fallback;
}

location @fallback {
  root /home/nodejs-project/public;
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```